# NumPy slicing over variable size, multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-slicing

Suppose having the following lines of code

```
import numpy as np

# The values equal to 1 inside this nested list indicate where the data need to be loaded. a = [7 x 6]
a = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, None, None],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, None, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, None, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, None, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, None, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, None, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, None, None]
]
# The list "a" cannot be modified for a number of reasons, so I create a np.array copy, named "b"
b = np.array(a)

N = int(1E7)  # Number of samples

# The loop below retrieves the positions inside "b" in which data need to be loaded
row = []
col = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    col.append([])
    if any(b[i] == 1):
        row.append(i)
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if b[i][j] is 1:
            b[i][j] = np.zeros((N, 1))
            col[i].append(j)


# Loading the data inside the selected positions of "b". "mydata" is a numpy array, whose shape is (N, 6)
for i in row:
    mydata = np.random.randn(N, len(a[0])).reshape(N, len(a[0])) # Generation of dummy data
    b[i, col[i]] = mydata[:, col[i]]  # This instruction returns a ValueError
```

However, I get the following error:
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (10000000,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)

Why does this type of slicing not work properly? Is it due to the variable size of the array elements inside "b"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The main goal I am trying to achieve here is avoiding a second loop `for j in col[i]`, after `for i in row` during the data loading process, just for sake of efficiency

Answer (score 0):

The slicing isn't working properly for cases where you inserted more than one zero array into the row because of using `b[i, col[i]]`.

Just consider your first row. This gives you `row=[0]`, `col =[[1,3]]`. This means that `b[0,0]` references the zeros arrays for columns 1 **and** 3. You should iterate over the rows and columns with a nested for loop as before

```
for i in row:
    for j in col[i]:
        mydata = np.random.randn(N, len(a[0])).reshape(N, len(a[0]))
        b[i, j] = mydata[:, col[i]]
```

Comment: The introduction of a nested loop was exactly what I wanted to avoid for efficiency purposes, since in a real scenario the "for j in col[i]" loop would be run for tens of thousands of times. Are there any other ways to solve this issue?

Comment: To ask the naive question: why not just initialize `mydata` before looping through `b` and directly assign the values from `mydata` to any position with a 1, without bothering with the row and col lists and the zeros arrays? Does that have an efficiency penalty?

Comment: I have generated somme dummy data just to simplify the discussion but, in a real scenario, I have to extract such data from several thousands of different .h5 files. Each .h5 file contains approx 6000 samples and corresponds to a given row of the nested list `a`: therefore I have to load in `b` just the portion of data corresponding to the positions  in `a` equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

Let's reduce the `N` to something rational, and add some prints:

```
print(row)
print(col)
print(a)
print(b)
```

A run:

```
0942:~/mypy$ python3 stack60813103.py 
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[[1, 3], [], [2], [1, 3, 5], [3], [], [0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 1, None, None], [0, 0, 0, 0, None, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, None, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, None, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, None, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, None, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, None, None]]
[[0 array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]]) 0
  array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]]) None
  None]
 [0 0 0 0 None 0]
 [0 0 array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]]) 0
  None 0]
 ....
 [0 0 0 0 None 0]
 [array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]]) 0 0 0
  None None]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack60813103.py", line 38, in <module>
    b[i, col[i]] = mydata[:, col[i]]  # This instruction returns a ValueError
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (5,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

`row`, `col` and `a` are lists, `b` is object dtype array (because of all the `None`).  Your loop has inserted a bunch of `np.zeros((N,1))` arrays.

`mydata` is a (N,5) float array.

`mydata[:, col[i]]` will then be (N,2) when `col[0]` is `[1, 3]`; for other `i` it could be (N,0) or (N,1), (N,3).

`b[i, col[i]]` is (2,) (or (0,),(1,),(3,)).  There's a rather obvious mismatch in shapes.  You can't put a bit (N,2) array into a (2,) slot.

Why are you trying to construct an array like this?  A mix of `None`, numbers, and arrays that have shapes like (N,1) and (N,2)?

---

I think you need to add an iteration:

```
for j in col[i]:
    b[i, j] = mydata[:, j]
```

That should assign a (N,) array to the `b[i,j]` element of `b`.

Comment: To give additional context, the values in the list `a` correspond to the buttons selected by a user in a GUI. When `a[i][j] = 0`, a given "channel" has not been selected by the user; when `a[i][j] = 1`, the channel has been selected; `a[i][j] = None`, instead, corresponds to a disabled button that cannot be pressed.
Since I am working with relatively large data (`N > 1E7`), I cannot create a huge matrix of zeros because it would result in eccessive memory allocation. Moreover, I also need to preserve in `b` the specific arrangement that was disposed in `a` for later use

Comment: Keep in mind that object dtype arrays are essentially lists.  The elements are objects.  It's a bit easier to view an object dtype array as 2d (as opposed to nested lists), but iteration on a list is faster.  Fast `numpy` math is not available.  See my edit for getting around this assignment error.

Comment: Ok, so I have accept a second `for` loop: `for j in col[i]`, there is no other way around it. Anyways, thank you very much for the advice, I will create `b` as a new list, instead of a `np.array`, then.